# Unable to generate row of Enemies, only one enemy being generated :\

Tags: java

Controller Class:

```
 package com.game.src.main;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Controller 
    {
        private LinkedList<Enemy> e = new LinkedList<Enemy>();

        Random r = new Random();

        Enemy TempEnemy = null;

        Game game;
        Textures tex;

        public Controller(Game game, Textures tex)
        {
            this.game = game;
            this.tex = tex;

            **for(int x = 0; x < (Game.WIDTH * Game.SCALE); x += 21)
                addEnemy(new Enemy(x, 200, tex));**
        }

        public void tick()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
                TempEnemy = e.get(i);

            TempEnemy.tick();
        }

        public void render(Graphics g)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
                TempEnemy = e.get(i);

                TempEnemy.render(g);
        }

        public void addEnemy(Enemy block)
        {
            e.add(block);
        }

        public void removeEnemy(Enemy block)
        {
            e.remove(block);
        }
    }
```

My for-Loop in the constructor is not creating a row of Enemies. What it should do, is it should render a row of enemy sprites, but instead it renders the last one at the far right corner of screen. :\ Enemy Class is as follow:

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Enemy 
{
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private Textures tex = null;

    public Enemy(int x, int y, Textures tex)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.tex = tex;
    }

    public void tick()
    {
        y+= 3;
        if(y >= (Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE))
            y = 0;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(tex.spike, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

Texture Class:

```
    package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Textures 
{
    public BufferedImage player, spike;

    private SpriteSheet ss;

    public Textures(Game game)
    {
        ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());
        getTextures();
    }

    private void getTextures()
    {
        player = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 44, 65);
        spike = ss.grabImage(1, 3, 21, 65);

    }

    public void setUp()
    {
        player = ss.grabImage(3, 1, 43, 65);
    }

    public void setDown()
    {
        player = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 43, 65);
    }

    public void setLeft()
    {
        player = ss.grabImage(5, 1, 43, 65);
    }

    public void setRight()
    {
        player = ss.grabImage(7, 1, 43, 65);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question on my side: Why do you use a TempEnemy Variable? You could write `e.get(i).render(g)` or `e.get(i).tick()` or did I missed something?

Comment: Interesting fact is, i didn't know i could directly use that method u mentioned. After checking, it generated a whole row :D Learned something today. I think that extra add-in variable TempEnemy was creating problem :\ but why ? :\

Comment: You found the answer in the answers ^^

Answer (score 2):

BRACKETS!

Change this

```
    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
            TempEnemy = e.get(i);

            TempEnemy.render(g);
    }
```

to this

```
    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++){
            TempEnemy = e.get(i);
            TempEnemy.render(g);
        }
    }
```

PS : Always write brackets for cycles, if-statements etc., even when you only need execute one line. You avoid this kind of struggles.

---

Also you do not need "TempEnemy", this code does the same :

```
    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++){
            e.get(i).render(g);
        }
    }
```

Comment: His `tick()` method also misses the brackets

Comment: @MuratK. - yea, there can be multiple missing brackets, I will not check all his code, he should add brackets everywhere as I mentioned and he will be ok :).

Comment: Thanks ! Tried it, i thought TempEnemy.render(g); must be outside before, but since it renders each enemy object, it must be included in for-body !